# Passing a component props and using inside a Swith case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, components, react-props

I've been trying to pass a props (i have a NavigationItem and there i have a "key" propriety) and use that key as as parameter inside a switch case in a cointainer, but it simply gives me a "Undefined" feedback. So here's the component code:

```
<div className={classes.espacamento}  id="playstation">
                        <NavigationItem key={"playstation"} link="/produtos">
                            Playstation
                    </NavigationItem>
                    </div>

                    <div className={classes.espacamento}  id="xbox">
                        <NavigationItem key={"xbox"} link="/produtos">
                            Xbox
                    </NavigationItem>
                    </div>
```

I export as a "navigationItens" but that just won't work

```
import NavigationItens from '../../components/Navigation/Navbar/NavigationItens';

class Produtos extends Component {
    loadProdutosHandler() {
        if (!this.props.produtos) {
        switch(this.props.navigationItens.key) {
            case 'PS4':
                developmentServer.get('jogos')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.props.updateProdutosHandler(response.data.data);
                    });

                console.log("xbox")
                break;

            case 'playstation':
                developmentServer.get('jogos?plataforma=PS4')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.props.updateProdutosHandler(response.data.data);
                    });
                break;

            default:
             developmentServer.get('jogos?plataforma=PS4')
            .then(response => {
                this.props.updateProdutosHandler(response.data.data);
            });
                }
            }
    }
```

Can someone help me on that? im a react beginner and im very confused right now haha

Comment: `key` is a reserved `prop` name. Try to change it.

Comment: oops sorry @devserkan I answered the same thing, you're too quick for me :)

Comment: No problem @RoseRobertson. This should have been an answer. So, upvoted yours :)

Comment: i changed to "item" the old prop "key", but it keeps giving me undefined
Also, thanks for the that reserved prop tip, bro!

Comment: I just looked at your code again and there are some things that I can't understand. How is the shape of  `NavigationItens` component? What is `props.navigationsItens`? Since you are trying to get the `key` property from it? Are they coming from your Redux store? What thing is certain, if you pass a prop to your component like this it can't be `undefined` since it is just a hardcoded string. Though you don't need here the curly braces, since you are passing a string, but you should get it from your component if there is not any typo or some other mistake like this.

Comment: Also, I can't see `NavigationItens` component anywhere in your code. `Produtos` component is not related to your question, right?

Answer (score 1):

`key` has a special meaning in react and so when you try to pass it down as a prop your component won’t see it (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) From the documentation -

> If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name

Comment: how i could do that? also i changed the "key" prop to "item" so it (should) work properly

Comment: A bit tricky but looking @ your code because there's possibly not enough context but maybe the issue is that you need to use `this.props.item` not `this.props.navigationItens.item`

Comment: hmm, that was really a problem, too. Im using this.props.item now, but it keeps giving me undefined. At least, i think im pretty close now haha